# What is the difference between the cogroup and joins in PIG?

Tags: apache-pig

```
Using Apache PIG.

Sample Data: {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8}.
```

I want the output in the following manner :

> {1,2},{2,3},{3,4},{4,5},{5,6},{6,7},{7,8}

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are looking for.See here for [COGROUP](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#COGROUP) & [GROUP](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#GROUP)

Now for the question related to the data.

Load the numbers, filter the numbers to exclude 8, then foreach number generate number,number + 1.

```
A = LOAD 'data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (numbers:int);
B = FILTER A BY (numbers < 8)
C = FOREACH B GENERATE numbers, numbers+1;
DUMP C;
```